# Android JsonReader can't iterate json array

Tags: android, json, jsonreader

I'm playing with `JsonReader` which is a streaming JSON parser in Android, and I met a problem that the parser won't go over all the items in an json array, it will only return me the first item.

Here's the code I use to do the parsing:

```
private ArrayList<Result> readResultsArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();

    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("results")){
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                results.add(readResult(reader));
            }
            reader.endArray();
        } else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();

    return results;
}
```

I'm sure that the method `readResult(reader)` would parse and return the first object in the array without any problem.

But the reader seemed just "ignore" the second object in the array.

Here's the `readResult(reader)` method:

```
    private Result readResult(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

        String from_user = null, 
                from_user_id_str = null, 
                from_user_name = null,
                text = null;
        Geo geo = null;
        URL profile_image_url = null;

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("from_user")){

                from_user = reader.nextString();
                Log.i(TAG, from_user);
            } else if (name.equals("from_user_id_str")) {

                from_user_id_str = reader.nextString();
                Log.i(TAG, from_user_id_str);
            } else if (name.equals("from_user_name")) {

                from_user_name = reader.nextString();
                Log.i(TAG, from_user_name);
            } else if (name.equals("geo")) {

                reader.beginObject();

                while(reader.hasNext()) {
//                      String s = reader.nextName();
                        if (name.equals("coordinates")) {
                            reader.beginArray();
                            double latitude = 0;
                            double longitude = 0;
                            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                latitude = reader.nextDouble();
                                longitude = reader.nextDouble();
                                Log.i(TAG, latitude + ", " + longitude);
                            geo = new Geo(latitude, longitude);
                        }
                        reader.endArray();
                    } else {
                        reader.skipValue();
                    }
                }
                reader.endObject();

            } else if (name.equals("profile_image_url")) {

                profile_image_url = new URL(reader.nextString());

            } else if (name.equals("text")) {

                text = reader.nextString();
                Log.i(TAG, text);
            } else {

                reader.skipValue();

            }

        }
        reader.endObject();


        return new Result(from_user, from_user_id_str, from_user_name, text, geo, profile_image_url);
    }

}
```

Here's the JSON I tried to parse:

(It is a Twitter search response, the original response is presented like below, [Link](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%E5%90%83&geocode=51.483372,-3.190826,200mi))

```
{
  "completed_in": 0.067,
  "max_id": 320160565840457730,
  "max_id_str": "320160565840457730",
  "page": 1,
  "query": "%E5%90%83",
  "refresh_url": "?since_id=320160565840457730&q=%E5%90%83&geocode=51.483372%2C-3.190826%2C200mi",
  "results": [
    {
      "created_at": "Fri, 05 Apr 2013 13:06:41 +0000",
      "from_user": "missmanchu",
      "from_user_id": 359296258,
      "from_user_id_str": "359296258",
      "from_user_name": "miss manchu ",
      "geo": null,
      "location": "London, United Kingdom",
      "id": 320160565840457730,
      "id_str": "320160565840457730",
      "iso_language_code": "ja",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3470783234/6ae4049d90a052c7a9c7f86ec804e523_normal.jpeg",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3470783234/6ae4049d90a052c7a9c7f86ec804e523_normal.jpeg",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/download/iphone&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPhone&lt;/a&gt;",
      "text": "RT @lougirlie: Delish Taiwanese-style bao by @missmanchu for lunch. 好吃！ http://t.co/clRznskvqe"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Fri, 05 Apr 2013 11:45:09 +0000",
      "from_user": "lougirlie",
      "from_user_id": 154974289,
      "from_user_id_str": "154974289",
      "from_user_name": "Louise Chow",
      "geo": {
        "coordinates": [
          51.5216788595,
          -0.1420583511
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": 320140044142772224,
      "id_str": "320140044142772224",
      "iso_language_code": "ja",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "place": {
        "full_name": "Westminster",
        "id": "548c2b8e3921a85a",
        "type": "CITY"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1750994903/photo_3__4__normal.JPG",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1750994903/photo_3__4__normal.JPG",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com&quot;&gt;Twitter for  iPhone&lt;/a&gt;",
      "text": "Delish Taiwanese-style bao by @missmanchu for lunch. 好吃！ http://t.co/clRznskvqe"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Fri, 05 Apr 2013 10:09:25 +0000",
      "from_user": "geleikai",
      "from_user_id": 351512769,
      "from_user_id_str": "351512769",
      "from_user_name": "geleikai",
      "geo": null,
      "location": "53.762824,-2.707418",
      "id": 320115951339200512,
      "id_str": "320115951339200512",
      "iso_language_code": "zh",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3110335584/545b94d39e1628d747428c73a8052bf8_normal.jpeg",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3110335584/545b94d39e1628d747428c73a8052bf8_normal.jpeg",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.wechatapp.com&quot;&gt;WeChat App&lt;/a&gt;",
      "text": "吃过午饭，前往阿姆斯特丹 http://t.co/LbQ0Jh7Mfp"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Thu, 04 Apr 2013 10:15:05 +0000",
      "from_user": "hpfly",
      "from_user_id": 60939059,
      "from_user_id_str": "60939059",
      "from_user_name": "0C哈根达斯",
      "geo": null,
      "location": "53.805042,-1.544011",
      "id": 319754991692824576,
      "id_str": "319754991692824576",
      "iso_language_code": "zh",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3251267049/c56ca4cb888736299548e5454a9d923b_normal.jpeg",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3251267049/c56ca4cb888736299548e5454a9d923b_normal.jpeg",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://fanfou.com&quot;&gt;fanfou2.0&lt;/a&gt;",
      "text": "现在对谈恋爱一点欲望都没有，更多的欲望是告诉我，我内心希望独享一个人的时光。现在特别希望晚睡，而且是晚上一个人吃着宵夜，看着电视。#如果生活可以这么单纯就好了##当然这也是晚睡的牵强理由#"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Wed, 03 Apr 2013 15:47:50 +0000",
      "from_user": "cushingliu",
      "from_user_id": 87816289,
      "from_user_id_str": "87816289",
      "from_user_name": "Cushing",
      "geo": {
        "coordinates": [
          0.0,
          0.0
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": 319476345325359104,
      "id_str": "319476345325359104",
      "iso_language_code": "zh",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "place": {
        "full_name": "Batu Ampar",
        "id": "ddc693317ed3f226",
        "type": "CITY"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3269471232/f89db3764b70bada908ab340a9fb9c85_normal.jpeg",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3269471232/f89db3764b70bada908ab340a9fb9c85_normal.jpeg",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://tapbots.com/tweetbot&quot;&gt;Tweetbot for iOS&lt;/a&gt;",
      "text": "有妈妈做饭吃的感觉真好"
    }
  ],
  "results_per_page": 15,
  "since_id": 0,
  "since_id_str": "0"
}
```

The only part I'm interested in is `"results"`, which is an array of two objects.

After took a close look at the example in [Android Developers - JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) as well as this [nice tutorial](http://tech.xtremelabs.com/parsing-json-data-efficiently-on-android-jsonreader/), I found mine is basically no difference with theirs.

So what's wrong with my code? Why it cannot itinerate the json array?

## UPDATE

Pasted the code of `readResult(reader)`

Comment: I believe the term you want is iterate, not itinerate.

Comment: Even though you're sure that *"`readResult(reader)` would parse and return the first object in the array without any problem"*, is there any chance you may not be closing the object properly? I.e. perhaps there's a call to `reader.endObject()` missing in there? It'd be good to share the code for `readResult(reader)` too.

Comment: I, too, suspect that readResult is being too hungry and eating up more of the json than you suspect.  It really looks like the most likely culprit, even though we don't have the source.  You're other stuff looks really straightforward.

Comment: @MH. thx mate, I'll update my question with the `readResult(reader)` method

Comment: @HalR thanks for the help, I'll update my question with more info :-)

Comment: @MH. Hi, I've pasted the code of `readResult(reader)`. It seemed I have closed the `readObject` properly, but could u please help me to point out what else might be wrong? thx!

Comment: @HalR Hi I've updated my answer with the code of readResult(reader). It seemed I have closed the `readObject` properly, could u please help me to point out what else might be wrong? thx!

Comment: @ss1271 Your `readResult()` method does not handle the 'result' element and its related BEGIN_ARRAY event. Modify your code to handle that.

Comment: @DeepakBala hi, I think I've handled in `if (name.equals("results")){
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                results.add(readResult(reader));
            }` which is located in `readResultArray()` method, is that correct?

Comment: @ss1271 I must have missed that when I skimmed over the code. Yes it appears you are handling it.

Comment: @ss1271 Which part of the JSON is skipped ? The one where the geo is null ? I modified the code a little and was able to read both `from_user` values.

Comment: @DeepakBala the problem I met, is the reader can only read the first object in the `result` array and ignore the second object (as you can see, the json file I posted has two objects in the `results` array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not accounting for null geo types which will cause an exception on the original code. Use `peek()` to check for null. I've modified the code to handle this and it prints both objects.

```
class MyReader
{
    public void readBegin(JsonReader reader)
    {
        try
        {
            reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext())
            {
                String name = reader.nextName();
                if (name.equals("results"))
                {
                    reader.beginArray();
                    while (reader.hasNext())
                    {
                        read(reader);
                    }
                    reader.endArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    reader.skipValue();
                }
            }
            reader.endObject();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void read(JsonReader reader) throws Exception
    {

        String from_user = null, from_user_id_str = null, from_user_name = null, text = null;
        URL profile_image_url = null;

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext())
        {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("from_user"))
            {
                from_user = reader.nextString();
                System.out.println(from_user);
            }
            else if (name.equals("from_user_id_str"))
            {

                from_user_id_str = reader.nextString();
            }
            else if (name.equals("from_user_name"))
            {

                from_user_name = reader.nextString();
            }
            else if (name.equals("geo"))
            {
                if (reader.hasNext())
                {
                    JsonToken peek = reader.peek();
                    if (peek == JsonToken.NULL)
                    {
                        reader.skipValue();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.beginObject();
                        while (reader.hasNext())
                        {
                            // String s = reader.nextName();
                            if (name.equals("coordinates"))
                            {
                                reader.beginArray();
                                double latitude = 0;
                                double longitude = 0;
                                while (reader.hasNext())
                                {
                                    latitude = reader.nextDouble();
                                    longitude = reader.nextDouble();
                                }
                                reader.endArray();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                reader.skipValue();
                            }
                        }
                        reader.endObject();
                    }
                }

            }
            else if (name.equals("profile_image_url"))
            {

                profile_image_url = new URL(reader.nextString());

            }
            else if (name.equals("text"))
            {

                text = reader.nextString();
            }
            else
            {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
    }
```

Comment: thx mate, so the problem is caused by the "null" object that I didn't handle?

Comment: thx! Would you please wait a few hours, I'll try your solution after work =)

Comment: Sure. Post a comment if you're stuck.

Comment: I applied your method but it still just read the first object in the array.

Comment: @ss1271 That is odd. My output shows both user names 'abc abc'. The json in your post is not well formed btw. I had to tweak it a little. Perhaps there are other elements that are null / missing in the json sent by twitter ?

Comment: hmm, I found strange also. FYI, I've updated my question with the original json response. THX in advance for helping me :D

Comment: @ss1271 Ran my code with the latest json. It does parse values correctly. Output - `missmanchu
lougirlie
geleikai
hpfly
cushingliu`

Comment: I'm confused about my code, just want to know what stopped it from go over all the objects in the array...is it because I'm adding these retrieved object via `results.add(readResult(reader));`?